# How to setup nth-of-type() to dynamically select elements in a certain order

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select elements in a certain order. I have an image carousel that could have any number of images but only 3 images show at a time. I need to add css styles to the 1st and 3rd image and different styles to the 2nd image.

The code below is a simplified version of what I am looking for. I need it to be dynamic as I dont know the number images the carousel will have. Is there a formula for example `nth-of-type(4n-7)`, that I can use to target this order dynamically?

```
li:nth-of-type(1),
li:nth-of-type(3),
li:nth-of-type(4),
li:nth-of-type(6),
li:nth-of-type(7),
li:nth-of-type(9) {
  color: red;
}


li:nth-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(5),
li:nth-of-type(8) {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select elements in a certain order"? The rest of the question doesn't mention any order.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code, with the carousel?

Comment: Ignoring the prose for now, if you mean you need three of the li elements (spread out over the entire list) to be blue and the rest red, without knowing in advance how many li elements there are, that is not easy with CSS alone. CSS doesn't have a child-count property you can utilise.

Comment: I agree with @MrLister. You will need to use JS. Paste your code and us help you.

Comment: Are these always shown in discrete groups of three (1-3) (4-6) etc... if so then it's pretty simple `:nth-of-type(3n+2)` - https://codepen.io/pen

Comment: The order is in the nth-of-type(). So looking at the code above I need the the 1,3,4,6,7,9 list item to be red and the 2,5,8 list item to be blue. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Done...see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your text you want to select every third image/item starting with the 2nd one.

If so the selector would be `element:nth-of-type(3n+2)`

```css
li:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n) { /* for demo only */
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
</ul>
```